# injecting ui-router-metatags to fountain js angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, meta-tags

Hey I am trying to use ui-router-metatags module in my project but it never works.
https://github.com/tinusn/ui-router-metatags

I followed the steps but at the end nothing. it is not showing error even.
I use yeoman fountain js generator for angular js and webpack.

I do npm install ui-router-metatags --save

this is my index.js file

```
var angular = require('angular');

var techsModule = require('./app/modules/techs/index');
require('angular-ui-router');
require('expose-loader?$!jquery');
var routesConfig = require('./routes');

var main = require('./app/main');
var header = require('./app/shared/header');
var title = require('./app/shared/title');
var footer = require('./app/shared/footer');
import 'bootstrap';
require('./index.scss');

angular
  .module('app', [techsModule, 'ui.router', 'ui.router.metatags'])
  .config(routesConfig)
  .component('app', main)
  .component('fountainHeader', header)
  .component('fountainTitle', title)
  .component('fountainFooter', footer);

function runBlock($rootScope, MetaTags) {
  $rootScope.MetaTags = MetaTags;
}

angular
.module('app')
.run(['$rootScope', 'MetaTags', runBlock]);

function myService() {
  var service = {
    getPosts: getPosts,
    getPost: getPost
  };

  var samplePost = {
    id: 1,
    title: 'sample blog post',
    content: 'lorem ipsum'
  };

  function getPosts(category) {
    return [samplePost];
  }

  function getPost(id) {
    return samplePost;
  }

  return service;
}

angular
.module('app')
.service('myService', myService);
```

and my routes.js look like that.

```
module.exports = routesConfig;

/** @ngInject */
function routesConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, UIRouterMetatagsProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
  UIRouterMetatagsProvider
  .setTitlePrefix('prefix - ')
  .setTitleSuffix(' | MyApp')
  .setDefaultTitle('MyApp')
  .setDefaultDescription('description')
  .setDefaultKeywords('keywords')
  .setStaticProperties({
    'fb:app_id': 'your fb app id',
    'og:site_name': 'your site name'
  })
  .setOGURL(true);
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider.state('app', {
    url: '/',
    component: 'app',
    metaTags: {
      title: 'Frontpage',
      description: 'This is the frontpage',
      keywords: 'lots of interresting keywords',
      properties: {
        'og:title': 'Frontpage'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

and for my html page I use this:

```
<title ng-bind="MetaTags.title">Default title</title>
  <meta name="description" content="{{MetaTags.description}}">
  <meta name="keywords" content="{{MetaTags.keywords}}">
  <meta ng-repeat="(key, value) in MetaTags.properties" property="{{key}}" content="{{value}}">
  <meta name="prerender-status-code" content="{{MetaTags.prerender.statusCode}}">
  <meta name="prerender-header" ng-if="MetaTags.prerender.header" content="{{MetaTags.prerender.header}}">
```

and for my web pack config I have this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const conf = require('./gulp.conf');
const path = require('path');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const FailPlugin = require('webpack-fail-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: [
          {loader: 'expose-loader', options: 'jQuery'},
          {loader: 'expose-loader', options: '$'}
        ]
      },

      {
        test: require.resolve('tether'),
        use: [
          {loader: 'expose-loader', options: 'Tether'}
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: [
          'json-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        loaders: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: [
          'ng-annotate-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: [
          'html-loader'
        ]
      },
      {test: require.resolve('jquery'), loader: 'expose-loader?$'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    FailPlugin,
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: conf.path.src('index.html')
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      options: {
        postcss: () => [autoprefixer]
      },
      debug: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      tether: 'tether',
      Tether: 'tether',
      'window.Tether': 'tether',
      Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
      // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
      Util: 'exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util',
      Dropdown: 'exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown'
    })
  ],
  devtool: 'source-map',
  output: {
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), conf.paths.tmp),
    filename: 'index.js'
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty'
  },
  entry: `./${conf.path.src('index')}`
};
```